# Telegram bot: how to persist and load user input data

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to make a Telegram bot (in golang, btw) which asks for some user input and persist this data for later processing. The problem is that I don't understand where to persist this user input? On the bot side? If yes then how can I make sure that one user's data won't be read by a different user? It must be some kind of authorisation?

The scenario that I'm talking about:

1. User 1 inputs "data 1"
2. The bot persists this "data 1" in a database
3. User 2 inputs "data 2"
4. The bot persists this "data 2" in a database
5. User 2 somehow makes a request to the bot and asks the "data 1" which belongs to User 1

So in the last step how can I prevent User 2 from reading User 1's data?